# How can I set checkbox list items as Checked by DEFAULT in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I need to show a list of checkbox list items as CHECKED in ALERTDIALOG by default(when the alertbox pops up) in android.

This is my code,

```
 final String[] items = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    final List<String> itemlist = Arrays.asList(items);


    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Working days")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, seletedvaluesbool, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                    seletedvaluesbool[indexSelected] = isChecked;

                    } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                        // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                    seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                    seletedvaluesbool[indexSelected] = isChecked;
                    }
                }
            }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel
                }
            }).create();
    dialog.show();

    }
```

When the dialog pops up, I need to show few items as Checked by default. I tried below code for that but it's not working.

```
    ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
    dialog.getListView().setSelection(0); //To set the 0th position as checked
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is selectedValuesBool?

Comment: @UmangBurman I have edited the code with 'selectedValuesBool' code for your reference.

Comment: `.setMultiChoiceItems(items, seletedvaluesbool, ` What is the value in this line

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
dialog.getListView().setSelection(0);
```

You should use this:

```
dialog.getListView().setItemChecked(0, true);
```